# How to specify a set of equivalent Functional Dependencies for a given relation

Tags: relational-algebra, functional-dependencies

[image]

We've been told that the FD are:

```
A->B
B->C
C->A
```

But with the transitive rule, since `A->B` and `B->C` this also means:

```
A->C
```

I worked out that:

`A->BC` is true, since `A->B` and `A->C` are FD. I can split `A->BC` to `A->B`, `A->C` with the **splitting rule**

`C->AB` is true, since `C->A` and due to **transit rule**: `C->B` is true (where `C->A`, `A->B` means `C->B`)

Can someone tell me the correct answer and why my answer is wrong. I can't get my head round the given answer.

Comment: Well, feedback is telling you *exactly* why your answer is wrong. You can't derive B->A from it.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' which answer is the correct one (to help me get my head round it)?

Comment: The right answer is the one whose closure matches the closure of set S1. Does your textbook teach you how to calculate the closure of a set of FDs?

Comment: There is no Splitting Rule (as explained by your answer) to the best of my knowledge. That is probably where the problem was with choosing #2. I guess you need to choose between #1 and #4 (both look tempting :)

Comment: What the OP calls "splitting", native English speakers call "decomposition".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion of why your answer is wrong can be found in the comments.

The correct answer is #4: only in this answer `A`, `B` and `C` are superkeys as in the original set of functional dependencies. In #1 `A` is not a superkey (e.g., `A -> B` does not hold), in #3 `C` is not a superkey (e.g., `C -> B` does not hold).

Comment: it's weird, I couldn't get my head round it but after leaving it for a few weeks it's all just clicked and seems extremely obvious now (I think I got carried away and over complicated things)! And to conclude, it's obviously not #2 due to `B` not being a superkey (e.g. `B -> C` does not hold)